# Validation "Formula1" referencing issue

Tags: excel, vba, validation

how do i reference a formula that uses quotations in excel VBA when trying to create a Validation table referencing. keep getting runtime error 1004

My dynamic table column reference is "CapitalWorks[Project Name]" I want to use this with the Indirect function.

The code:

`excelapp.ActiveSheet.Range("B3").Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="Indirect(""CapitalWorks[Project Name]"")"`

Cannot get this to work no matter what I can do, tried converting the whole formula to a string and referencing is, no cigar.

might be worth mentioning the table is in a different sheet, not sure if this is affecting the code although it shouldn't?

Comment: Why do you need Indirect in there? You do need an `=` sign at the start of the formula.

Answer (score 1):

### Data Validation Using Exel Table Column

- If you insist on using `ActiveSheet`, remember that you can always do `ActiveSheet.Parent.Worksheets("Sheet1")` to reference `Sheet1` in the same workbook.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ApplyDataValidationExcelTable()
    
    Const WorksheetName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const TableWorksheetName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const TableColumnAddress As String = "CapitalWorks[Project Name]"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    With wb.Worksheets(WorksheetName).Range("B3").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
        AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlEqual, _
        Formula1:="='" & TableWorksheetName & "'!" _
            & Range(TableColumnAddress).Address
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing 1 step and you don't need INDIRECT.

Create a name from the [Name Manager](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-name-manager-in-excel-4d8c4c2b-9f7d-44e3-a3b4-9f61bd5c64e4) linked to `CapitalWorks[Project Name]` and use that range:

In my example, this name is `R_LIST`:

[image]

Then create your validation list:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("F6").Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="=R_LIST"
```

Notice this part: `Formula1:="=R_LIST"`

And this is what I got:

[image]

If I add new values in the column, list gets autoupdated :)

[image]